# Changing more than one item's CSS with :target

Tags: html, css, target

Okay, so essentially, I have, say, 3 links, some text, then 3 divs. (eg:

```
<a href="#A">A</a><br/>
<a href="#B">B</a><br/>
<a href="#C">C</a><br/>
<p>Blah blah</p>
<div id="A">BlAh</div>
<div id="B">BlBh</div>
<div id="C">POMEGRANTE!</div>
```

Now, at the moment, you click A and jump to A, etc. and it highlights the div that it selects because of CSS's :target selector. But, I would also like to highlight link A (in a different way to the div) while having div A selected. Are there any ways in Javascript or CSS to do this that *don't* require weird and/or unstable workarounds?

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle for this?

Comment: you could give an "active" class to the link on click, would you care for a jquery solution?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/f4FF4/2/

Comment: No thanks to jquery, I'm not planning to install it and/or use it until absolutely necessary.

Comment: There's no installing, you just include the library and then DOM manipulation becomes a breeze ;) If you've never used it, you're definitely missing out, at least in what tasks like this are concerned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give an "active" class to the link upon click. Here's an implementation using jQuery

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2CzMb/)**

And a native Javascript one:

```
var elems =document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                    elems[i].className="";
                };
                this.className = "active";
        });
}
```

Comment: While it works on jsfiddle, neither examples work in a more complex document, even after removing CSS that could possibly conflict. I'll keep trying and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @DuyAnh are you trying the jQuery one? if so you need to wrap the code inside a `$(document).ready(function(){...})` jsfiddle does that by default, check this http://jsfiddle.net/2CzMb/1/

Comment: I've managed to get it working (the jquery one) in jsfiddle, but when I put the js into my actual HTML document and include the jquery library, it either wipes the page, or nothing changes.

Comment: And I also did the document ready, but it still doesn't work (in my HTML doc)

Comment: @DuyAnh that's strange... have you checked your browser's console for any errors? you can open the console by pressing Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome/Firefox

Comment: Okay, I opened the console, refreshed the page, and clicked the link, and.... it's empty.

Comment: @DuyAnh how about placing an `alert()` inside the document ready function just to test if it's being run

Comment: Nothing happened. I guess I didn't install the library correctly, but I'm using a jquery library stored on the server, as well as the one hosted by google.

Comment: @DuyAnh you think you could post all your page code in a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)? just to see how everything is set up?

Comment: @DuyAnh I found the issue, the problem is in the jquery script tag, remember you always need to use an opening and closing tag, it should look like this `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: So apparently `<blah/>` doesn't work for script tags. Good to know! I've ticked your answer, and thanks for the help!

Comment: @DuyAnh No problem, I'm glad we could make it work. Good look with your project :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this also..

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $('a').css('color','');
 $('a[href=#'+$(this).attr("id")+']').css('color','red');
})
```

Here you go:http://jsfiddle.net/f4FF4/6/

Comment: That one didn't work at all for me, unlike the one above (which did, but only on jsfiddle)

Comment: Update: Actually, it did work, but it didn't have the intended effect.